# How to make relation between legal (read only) tables with non standard RoR name definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two legal (read only) tables not made in RoR but in Postgresql. I can't change them. They are in one to one relation with foreign key in table imed_patient.

Table imed_operator has primary key on field code and it is not integer but string. Table imed_patient has primary key on field code (string too) and foreign key of table imed_operator on field r_opr_code.

I made declaration of legal tables :

```
class ImedOperator < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "imed_operator"
    self.primary_key = "code"

  has_one :imed_patient, foreign_key: 'r_opr_code'
end
```

and

```
class ImedPatient < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "imed_patient"
    self.primary_key = "code"

    belongs_to :imed_operator , foreign_key: 'r_opr_code'
end
```

I was thinking that i declare relation between tables on RoR style to use all functions, but it seems not. I started console and write code :

```
object = ImedOperator.where("code = '003387100000000000002000'")
```

It was succes:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ImedOperator code: "003387100000000000002000", active: "Y", gender: "N", login: nil, password: nil, first_name: nil, middle_name: nil, surname: nil, birthday: nil, pesel: nil, create_date: "2011-02-24 15:07:11", create_operator: "000000000000000000000000", update_date: nil, update_operator: nil, employed: "N", admin: "N", info: nil, lock_session: nil, bride_surname: nil, pass_create_date: "2013-02-01 18:03:26", mother_pesel: nil, id_number: nil, nip: nil, dtp_login: nil, dtp_password: nil, portal_account_enabled: "N", passport_id: nil, personal_id: nil>]>
```

I even check that it is ActiveRecord by code:

```
object.class
```

and receive result :

```
 => ImedOperator::ActiveRecord_Relation
```

but when I made code

```
object.is_homeless
```

with field *is_homeless* from table imed_patient (was thinking that relation is working) I receive error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `is_homeless' for #<ImedOperator::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000004439ca8>
```

What I can improve to use standard RoR joining of methods by relation ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `where` always returns an ActiveRecord::Relation, what you are missing is to explicitly indicate the record you want, basically you need to add `first`, something like:

`object = ImedOperator.where(code: '003387100000000000002000').first`

with that you should be able to call any active record method coming from your model

**UPDATE**

To get the attribute from the association:

`ImedOperator.where(code: '003387100000000000002000').first.imed_patient.is_homeless?`

of course assuming, that code exists and it has the `imed_patient` association.

Comment: Nothing changed - the same error. So first is not helping at all. Anyway thanks for idea.

Comment: What didn't work? What is the error? What is the table schema? Btw, "is_homeless" is not defined in ImedOperator, so you need to use "object. imed_patient.is_homeless"

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run the `is_homeless` method over the ActiveRecord::Relation collection you can do something like this:

```
object.map(&:is_homeless)
```

And if you want to add a little syntactic sugar maybe call your `is_homeless` `is_homeless?` instead. Assuming it is returning a boolean.

Comment: You are saying about map function, but I don't want to change it into array. I want to still use it as active records objects. So this is not I am looking for. I want to achieve something like this :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Jdc_WMQ8Ts